# C++ - DWORD Decimal to DWORD Hexadecimal

Tags: c++, dword

How can you convert a decimal to hexadecimal in C++? I've had success with ultoa but that gives you a char (and using (DWORD)Buffer to std::cout just ends in gibberish). Also i need to save the new hexadecimal in a DWORD again.

My Code so far:

```
//Vars
char Buffer[33];

// Client.dll
DWORD d_clientDll = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("client.dll");
_ultoa(d_clientDll, Buffer, 16);
std::cout << Buffer << std::endl;
std::cout << d_clientDll << std::endl;
```

Comment: @harold Not really.

Comment: @harold Since i want to save it into another DWORD then, which isn't the case in the other post.

Comment: OK that's easy just keep the old DWORD, there's no point in converting something to a string and then right back again

Comment: @harold No since i need the DWORD in hexadecimal format.

Comment: That doesn't exist. Only strings are decimal/hexadecimal/etc. A DWORD is the value itself, not in any base really - well you could argue that it's in base 2³², or that deep down it's in binary, but it's mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @harold This is basicly what i'm trying to achieve: https://hastebin.com/otozurariy.cpp

Comment: What type is clientDll

Comment: @harold It's DWORD

Comment: So it's just `Offsets::clientDll = d_clientDll;` then

Comment: @harold That would result in a decimal format. I need a hexadecimal one. (Like: public const Int32 m_ArmorValue = 0xAA04; but for C++)

Comment: No, DWORD doesn't have a decimal format. It doesn't have a hexadecimal format either. It has *no format*. 0xAA04 is the same number as 43524.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143048/discussion-between-harold-and-shuzuka).

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `std::hex` ?

```
std::cout << std::hex << d_clientDll << std::endl
```

Comment: Surprisingly this suddenly is working (was using a method with std::hex before, that didn't work). How would you save this into a DWORD now? (Offsets::clientDll = std::hex << d_clientDll; Doens't work.)